# Typescript - Assign object with extra property do not fail

Tags: typescript

Why this code do not fail when execute `a = b` ? [Play link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oA8D8AuKAdgK4C2ARhAE5oYh6GkXUC+KKokUAQgsjejnzFyVflABeQxqNYoANhGBQAhvjiIkrBUrL4eGyVACMs5bzJQA9JcIB7JQDNlASzlszB-Cas2nroA)

```
type A = {
    x?: number
    y?: number
}

type B = {
    x?: number
    z: number
}

let a: A = {}
let b: B = {z: 1}

a = b // not fail
a = {z: 1} // fail
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript uses [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system#:%7E:text=In%20structural%20typing%2C%20an%20element,features%20must%20match%20in%20name.)), an object of type `B` is a valid `A` object.

In your second example, [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) will prevent you to assign a literal that has nothing in common with `A`.